# How could I check If a zip file is corrupted in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip

I would check if a ZIP file is corrupted using NodeJS using less CPU and memory as possible.

How to corrupt a ZIP file:

1. Download a ZIP file
2. Open the ZIP file using a text editor optimized like Notepad++
3. Rewrite the header. Only put random characters.

I am trying to reach this goal using the NPM library "node-stream-zip"

```
  private async assertZipFileIntegrity(path: string) {
    try {
      const zip = new StreamZip.async({ file: path });
      const stm = await zip.stream(path);
      stm.pipe(process.stdout);
      stm.on('end', () => zip.close());
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error();
    }
  }
```

However, when I run the unit tests I receive an error inside an array:

Rejected to value: [Error]

Comment: edit your question to show us the output of `console.error(error)`

Comment: `throw new Error();` is pretty much pointless.  Your `catch` block gets an error object that contains useful information and you just throw that away and throw an empty error object with no information in it.  I can see no reason to ever do this.  Use the error object already given to you or if you're going to make your own error object, put some useful information in it from the original error object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import zip from 'yauzl';
import path from 'path';

const invalidZipPath = path.resolve('invalid.zip');
const validZipPath = path.resolve('valid.zip');

const isValidZipFile = (filePath) => {


    return zip.open(filePath, { lazyEntries: true }, (err, stream ) => {

        if (err) {
            
            console.log('fail to read ', filePath);
            return false;

        }
            
        console.log('success read ', filePath);
        return true;

    });

}

isValidZipFile(validZipPath);
isValidZipFile(invalidZipPath);
```